# Name the problem: dividing indexed coins in bins

Tags: combinatorics

Does any of you know the name of the problem described below? I am especially interested in possible generalizations of this problem.

I looked through my textbooks on combinatorics but could not find a similar problem.

**Problem Statement.** 
I have 36 different coins. Each side has a number printed on it ranging from 1 to 6.

With notation {Number<sub>SideA</sub>, Number<sub>SideB</sub>} this would give:

{1,1}, {1,2}, ..., {1,6}, 
{2,1}, {2,2}, ..., {2,6}, 
..., 
{6,1}, {6,2}, ..., {6,6}.

I want to divide all of these into a number of bins such that in each bin, there are at most 4 different indices on Side A and at most 4 different indices on Side B. 
Furthermore, any combination of 2 bins should contain coins with at most 5 different indices on Side A and at most 5 different indices on side B.

- What is the minimum number of bins for which this is possible?

Comment: you can think about partitioning your grid. And by grid I mean the 6x6 matrix the problem admits. This males it clear it can be done in 4 bins. But I don’t know if that will necessarily give you the min

Comment: Six bins is minimal as shown in my completely rewritten answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a variation of [Latin Square](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatinSquare.html). It is equivalent to ask how many colors are needed to color a 6x6 grid lattice such that:

1. each color occupies at most 4 grids of any row and any column.
2. no two color together occupies a whole row or a whole column.

This certainly cannot be done with two colors. The following example shows with 3 colors, this is possible.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> - What is the minimum number of bins for which this is possible?

My previous claim that 7 bins is minimal was incorrect. I wrote a short program in C to search for a solution in 6 bins. This is the output:

```
0 0 0 1 1 2
0 0 0 1 1 3
0 0 0 4 4 5
1 4 5 1 1 5
2 2 3 3 4 2
2 2 3 3 5 2
```

The numbers in this grid indicate which bin each coin is in. The indices for the coins are the (x, y) column and row values (not shown). This is **known to be a minimal solution** because the program would not have assigned any coin to the sixth bin if could be placed into one of the first five subject to the stated restrictions.